# KDTREE executable in Concorde

Tags: c, makefile, executable, traveling-salesman

I'm trying to use the kdtree executable in Concorde but after installation it isn't in the KDTREE directory(or anywhere else I looked).  I've tried rerunning the makefile and reinstalling Concorde but neither helped.  The README and Insallation guide lists a few other executables that are all created when I installed and it seems like kdtree should be created as well. I can't find anything in the documentation or online about how to make it.  Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking about the executable in `./TSP/concorde` ?

Comment: No, but it's similar.  I'm looking for ./KDTREE/kdtree  It's mentioned in this readme under Executable Programs.   http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/concorde/downloads/codes/src/970827/README

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `kdtree` executable is not compiled by default. You need to compile it as follows:

```
cd KDTREE
make kdtree
```

Once compiled, you will find the `kdtree` executable in the `KDTREE` directory:

```
$ ./kdtree
Usage: ./kdtree [- see below -] [tsplib_file or dat_file]
   -b:   dat file in binary-ints
   -w f  use node weights from file
   -W #  use random node weights (0, #)
   -k #  number of nodes for random problem
   -G #  use #x# grid for random points, no dups if #<0
   -s #  random seed
   -n #  find # nearest graph
   -q #  find quadrant # nearest graph
   -t    nearest neighbor tour
   -g    greedy tour
   -j    quick-boruvka tour
   -v    boruvka tour
   -f    farthest addition tour
   -z f  two_opt the given cycle
   -Z    run two_opt (default: on greedy)
   -x f  3_opt the given cycle
   -X    run 3_opt (default: on greedy)
   -h    use limited 3-swaps in two_opt
   -m    nearest neighbor 2-matcing
   -p    min spanning tree (prim)
   -o f  write the cycle or edge set to f
   -N #  norm (must specify if dat file is not a TSPLIB file)
         0=MAX, 1=L1, 2=L2, 18=JOHNSON
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!